# XCode cannot deploy application to AppStore.

Tags: iphone, xcode

Prior to Xcode 4.2 update, I have no problem in submitting my applications to the App Store via (Organizer) Archive, but now after the update, I always get "No Value" for Application. It should display my application name and version.

I have already created a new version in "iTunes Connect" and the status is now "Waiting for Upload".

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot submit applications to iTunes Connect with XCode 4.2 yet.  It is just beta - and it includes iOS5 which is also beta - you can submit to the Mac App store with XCode 4.1, but XCode 4.2 can't be used for App submission yet.