# Application failed codesign verification in application loader

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, code-signing, verification

I am using xcode 4.2 Build 4C151a. And I failed to submit my app through organizer because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886847/xcode-cannot-deploy-application-to-appstore).
 But app loader doesn't work either. It just gives a error:

**Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.**

I check build setting of Project and Targets. The code signing identity of release is iphone distribution. 
In Product > Edit Scheme , build configuration has already been change to release.
Xcode gives no error or warning when building and achieving. 
After google this error and read the [documents of Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG13), I use codesign cmd to check my app, 
but find nothing wrong:

```
$ codesign -dvvv /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AttentionDetector-gmmelanobmbjlbhahwbarnsctfdk/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/AttentionDetector.app
Executable=/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AttentionDetector-gmmelanobmbjlbhahwbarnsctfdk/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/AttentionDetector.app/AttentionDetector
Identifier=com.MyCom.MyName.AttentionDetector
Format=bundle with Mach-O thin (armv7)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=8122 flags=0x0(none) hashes=397+5 location=embedded
CDHash=727f1bb04fb535821626ce50b1a35bc2c638223a
Signature size=4315
Authority=iPhone Distribution: My Name
Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Signed Time=2013-5-6 下午02:43:10
Info.plist entries=28
Sealed Resources rules=3 files=18
Internal requirements count=1 size=148
```

Then I check the zip file, and find something confusing:

```
$ codesign -dvvv /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AttentionDetector-gmmelanobmbjlbhahwbarnsctfdk/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/AttentionDetector.zip
/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AttentionDetector-gmmelanobmbjlbhahwbarnsctfdk/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/AttentionDetector.zip: code object is not signed
```

I am not sure if this matters.

BTW my macbook is 32-bits, but my app is build for iOS 6.1 ( may require 64-bits?).
I just copy the SDK of Xcode 4.6 into my Xcode 4.2. The app works well when debuging in my iPad (iOS 6.1.2).

Thanks for your answer.

EDIT1:
Thanks to @Rushabh. I check the entitlements, which I haven't modified, with

```
security cms -D -i MyApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision
```

, getting this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AppIDName</key>
    <string>Attention Detector</string>
    <key>ApplicationIdentifierPrefix</key>
    <array>
        <string>XJJGWB4EW6</string>
    </array>
    <key>CreationDate</key>
    <date>2013-05-04T12:31:30Z</date>
    <key>DeveloperCertificates</key>
    <array>
        <data>
        ...
        </data>
    </array>
    <key>Entitlements</key>
    <dict>
        <key>application-identifier</key>
        <string>XJJGWB4EW6.com.MyCom.MyName.AttentionDetector</string>
        <key>aps-environment</key>
        <string>production</string>
        <key>get-task-allow</key>
        <false/>
        <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
        <array>
            <string>XJJGWB4EW6.*</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>ExpirationDate</key>
    <date>2014-02-25T12:31:30Z</date>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Attention Detector</string>
    <key>TeamIdentifier</key>
    <array>
        <string>XJJGWB4EW6</string>
    </array>
    <key>TeamName</key>
    <string>My Name</string>
    <key>TimeToLive</key>
    <integer>297</integer>
    <key>UUID</key>
    <string>F0636A25-B371-4FEF-906B-C2979028F218</string>
    <key>Version</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

There are two differences: I get this line but others don't

```
<key>aps-environment</key>
```

Besides, I get

```
Authority=iPhone Distribution: My Name
```

instead of

```
Authority=iPhone Distribution: My Name(XXXXXXXX)
```

In my keychain access, I find two distribution certifications: one is "iPhone distribution: My name" and the other is "iPhone distribution: My name (XXXXXXXXX)". Both are valid, but can I delete the former one? The former one was created when I first apply for Apple developer account.

EDIT2: fix the problem of "MyName(XXXXX)". I delete one of  the certificates, download the new provision file. Now I get My name (XXXXXXX), But the error still exist!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272863/how-to-solve-application-failed-codesign-verification-when-uploading-to-itunes

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But here I get:  "Authority=iPhone Distribution: My Name" not "Authority=iPhone Developer: My Name".